# How to Pass Tablename, Fieldnames, Values as perameters in Stored Procedure using CI?

Tags: sql-server, codeigniter

I am developing a custom application using CodeIgniter and MSSQL Server. Here i am using stored procedures. 
Now i am wondering to implement codeigniter query type functionality where i can create a universal stored procedure in SQL Server and at the time of using i can pass tablename, array of fields and values. 
It can work for both insert and update.

Something like we do in CodeIgniter to execute the query,

```
    $data = array('fieldname1' => 'value1',
'fieldname2' => 'value2');

$this->db->insert($tablename,$data);
```

Just like this if we can pass the table name and array of the data to stored procedure and stored procedure automatically execute it.

If this can be done, it can save lots n lots of man hours. If anyone have already done i will be very much happy to see the solution.

Comment: so you need stored procedure in sql server, where table name, column name and column value passed as string and saved in db.

Comment: Yes i mean, the same way we do in CI to store the data into the table, but using the stored procedure

Comment: @M.Hemant: Page not found on your link.

Comment: remove last big bracket `]` from URL and try again typo mistake is there

Comment: @M.Hemant; it is almost like answer but here in the procedure it is already defined the table name, fields etc. What i want is, we pass the table name and fields from the codeigniter only. Just like we do while insert into database normally.

Comment: @M.Hemant ; we can call it like, reusable procedure for different models and tables.

Comment: just pass extra table name in an array and read it in SP

Comment: And what about custom fields array? Main concern is that only.  We can pass Whole array containing the fields name and it's value that to be inserted

Comment: please read whole that article carefully you just need to add extra table name in an array that's it

Answer (score 0):

You need to make string very specific in this case.
Figure out your table name, Column name, Column values for insert. For update 2 more parameters are required Id column name and its value.

```
    GO
    ---- exec InsertUpdate  'tablename', 'col1, col2, col3', 'val1, val2, val3', 'idcol', 'idval'
    GO
    Create proc InsertUpdate 
    ( @TableName nvarchar(500), 
      @ColName nvarchar(max), 
      @ColValues nvarchar(max), 
      @IDColName nvarchar(100) = '', --- for update only otherwise null
      @IdColValue nvarchar(Max) = '' --- for update only otherwise null
    )
    As
    Begin
    declare @Query nvarchar(max)

    if (@IdColValue = '')
    Begin

    set @Query = ' Insert into ' + @TableName + ' (' + @ColName + ') values (' + @ColValues + ')'

    End
    Else
    Begin

    ;with CtColumn as (
    select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select 1000)) as Slno, * from Split(@ColName,',') )
    , CtValue as (
    select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select 1000)) as Slno, * from Split(@ColValues, ','))
    , CTFinal as (
    select CCOl.Slno, CCOl.Items as ColName, CVal.Items as ColValue  from CtColumn as CCOl inner join CtValue as CVal on CCOl.Slno=CVal.Slno )
    select @Query = 'update ' + @TableName + ' set ' + 
    stuff ( (select ',' + ColName + '=' + ColValue from CTFinal for xml path ('')) ,1,1,'') + 
    ' where ' + @IDColName + '=' + @IdColValue

    End

    exec sp_executesql @Query
    End

    Go
```

Comment: Yes this is quite similar to my question yet, in your solution we can only pass single column and values but i want multiple. i.e. in some case there will be 2 columns, in some case there will be 6 etc. So we need to pass the array and want to parse it.

Comment: no you can make any number of column names in comma separated string

Comment: Yes i got that and it worked like a charm. Just curious what to do in case of UTF-8 values. i.e. we can pass it using N'value' . How can we pass it over here?

Comment: Try to pass your string in N'value' format, I think it worked.

Comment: No not really as we need to pass string in single quote so it mismatches the perameters

Comment: see some example to pass your final string into parameter in sql, or give me some example of your data which mismatches. Let see what best can you get :)